# Function template not requiring an explicit instantiation when called from instantiated function template

Tags: c++, templates, explicit-instantiation, template-instantiation

I have a function template calling another function template. The first one is explicitly instantiated whereas the second one isn't.

I realize that by instantiating the template, a function with the given type is created. But does that mean that any called function template (from within the previous function) is also instantiated?

See the code below to understand what I mean:

**main.cpp:**

```
    #include "library.hpp"
    
    int main() {
      std::vector<int> vec = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
      Library::print_vector(vec);
    
      return 0;
    }
```

**library.hpp:**

```
    #ifndef LIBRARY_HPP
    #define LIBRARY_HPP
    
    #include <vector>
    
    namespace Library {
      template <typename T>
      void print_vector(const std::vector<T>& vec);
    
      template <typename T>
      void print(T x);
    }
```

**library.cpp:**

```
#include <iostream>

#include "library.hpp"

template <typename T>
void Library::print_vector(const std::vector<T>& vec) {
  for (T x : vec)
    print(x);
}

template <typename T>
void Library::print(T x) {
  std::cout << "x: " << x << '\n';
}

// explicit template instantiation
// no template instantiation for Library::print(), and yet no linking error!!!
template void Library::print_vector(const std::vector<int>&);
```

Comment: In order to compile `void Library::print_vector(const std::vector<int>&);`, it must also compile `void Library::print(int);`

Comment: _"does that mean that any called function template (from within the previous function) is also instantiated?"_ - I would say yes.

Comment: Yes, and at that, you don't need the declaration, your last line. It does not do anything. If you had `template<>` the last line, then you would get a linker error.

Comment: @lakeweb, the last line should avoid an `undefined reference` linking error.

Comment: @lakeweb The implementation is in the `.cpp` file so without the explicit instantiation, linking would fail if `print` or `print_vector` was used used with any `T`. At least with explicit instantiation, `T` is allowed to be `int`.

Comment: Hi @Hakim, seems we posted at the same time. The `template` without at least a `<>` does not make sense to me. But the MSC compiler just ignores it.

Comment: @lakeweb [Function template / Explicit instantiation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template#Explicit_instantiation) - the code in the question is in the second form: `template return-type name ( parameter-list ) ;` where the template parameter is deduced to `int`.

Comment: hi @Ted Lyngmo. And here I thought I was really getting this. Instantiation without a definition.... Always a catch :) I'll do more reading..... Thanks.